# HTTP post to the ASPX page from Java code doesn't hit the page

Tags: asp.net, networking, iis-6, port, network-protocols

I am running into a issue and will appreciate any help or pointers:

A third party system running java application running on appache is making a http post to a ASPX page (.net 4.0) but the request is not reaching to the page. I do see the requests coming to IIS from IIS logs but its not hitting the page (based on results on my log file). I have confirmed that everything, including logging, work when I make the http post to the same page via a test html page.

Looks like IIS is blocking when the request is coming from java code. I am not getting anything concrete while doing search...any help or pointer will be greatly appreciated!!
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe some code would help to resolve your issues... :) Java or not java, a request is a request and it doesn't matter if it comes from a browser or some other program. That's why HTTP was made for, to create a unified protocol for communication. If you can use a browser to access the page, you can use any program that follows the same rules. So, I believe there's a problem with your code rather than with some settings in IIS.. :) IIS doesn't know your program was written in Java.

Comment: Sharing the java code that makes the request would help

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, its a 3rd party system and all I can do there is specify a URL where they send data via form post.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that .net was rejecting the request as the data passed in form post was XML and it was thinking its too dangerous :-). I have to add following to web.config in system.web section to work :

This was only happening when request was coming from 3rd party source system and not from my test page which was from same server.

Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: You forgot to mention what exactly you had to add to your web.config :)